# How do I install the Flash Debug Player with IE10?

Tags: flash, internet-explorer-10

For the same of testing (and debugging...) my Flex application on Windows 8 (which comes with IE10), I just downloaded the [Flash Debug Player 11.4.402.287](http://download.macromedia.com/pub/flashplayer/updaters/11/flashplayer_11_ax_debug.exe) - however, trying to install it merely shows a message box saying

> The installation encountered errors: Your Microsoft Internet Explorer browser includes the latest version of the Adobe Flash Player built-in. Windows Update will inform you when new versions of the Flash Player are available.

I'm using Internet Explorer 10.0.9200.16384 on Windows 8. A bit of Google research suggested that IE10 has a Flash player built-in (similiar to what Google Chrome has) so I looked for a way to disable the player. It seems that this is indeed possible by clicking the Cogwheel icon in the IE10 toolbar and then selecting 'Manage Add-ons'. The dialog which shows up shows a 'Shockwave Flash Object' entry. However, even with the built-in Flash player disabled, the Flash Debug Player installer keeps giving the same message.

Does anybody know how I can install the Flash Debug Player in IE10?

Comment: According to the release notes (even the 11.5 beta), the *“ActiveX Flash Player in this release is not compatible with Windows 8. Flash Player for Windows 8 is available as part of the Windows 8 release preview.”*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Flash debug player for IE10 is now available at [Adobe Flash Player Support Center](http://www.adobe.com/support/flashplayer/downloads.html#fp11).

Comment: is there one for firefox on windows?

Answer (score 3):

Adobe [posted on their forum](http://forums.adobe.com/message/4652105) about this:

> Sorry for the lack of information on the content debugger for Win 8. 
>   The debugger will be available for download on Microsoft's website a
>   few weeks after Windows 8 general availability (10/26).

So it seems like it's not available yet, but should be in the next few weeks.

**Update**

The flash debug player is now available [on the adobe website](http://www.adobe.com/support/flashplayer/downloads.html#fp11).

Comment: Thanks for digging up that link. Not the answer I hoped for, but well - that's the thing with the correct answers. They are not always what you hoped for. :)